# what's the best way to learn C++ and Qt at the same time?

Tags: c++, qt4

Hi I did A Google search and couldn't find anything,

so I wanna learn Qt/C++ my University (I'm a first year CompSci Student) won't be teaching C++ next year which is a big disappointment

I already know Python
and dabbled in LaTeX, Javascript, C++

I'm currently helping out a free software project [Clementine](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/) but it's programmed in Qt/C++ and I don't know enough of both to help out enough.

Is there any tips, Tutorial, howtos out there?

Answer (score 13):

Don't learn both at the same time. Learn C++, then learn Qt. Grab a [book about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), then a [book about Qt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271476); there is no substitute for a good book.

Trying to learn C++ and Qt at the same time is like trying to learn the alphabet while reading Shakespeare.

Comment: +1: Because you compare `Qt` with Shakespeare, and I loooove `Qt` :)

Comment: +1: Because you compare `Qt` with Shakespeare, whose writing predates the adoption of a standardised language and therefore reads rather strangely when compared to modern writing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an impossible thought learning both at the same time. Since you already know Python, try learning some basic Qt concepts by implementing something simple in [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/). Learn C++ by writing simple console programs. Once you've mastered C++, try doing the same stuff with Qt using C++. It's a fact that you'll get a lot more help and code examples from people using C++, so you shouldn't just be satisfied with using Python to implement Qt programs.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt's website: [How to learn Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/how-to-learn-qt.html) and [Qt tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/tutorials.html).
Since you're familiar with programming already, the [Best Practices](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/best-practices.html) might be of interest too.

Comment: "We assume that you already know C++ and will be using it for Qt development" Sorry already looked at that